# would it be possible to make git (or some command line wrapper) prompt me before first adding/committing and/or pushing a file greater than X bytes?

Tags: git, wrapper, large-files

I would like to be notified and asked to confirm (script pauses, required to type 'y\n' to continue) before successfully running `git add`, `git commit` or `git push` (**) on a NEWLY ADDED file greater than a certain size. (I know this is effectively impossible to do safely and automatically with pre-existing files)

Git itself (Linus) acknowledges that it is slow with larger (>>10MB) individual files and so I was first of all wondering whether or not there are option(s) embedded within git which would caution me and ask for a 'y' confirmation every time I add (&/or commit) a NEW file greater than a certain size?

If not are there any open source projects for metaprogramming (as it were) on top of git? I code in ruby and can imagine it might be fairly simple to run my git "migrations" from inside of a wrapper of some kind.

(**) I don't host a git server, and don't plan on it any time soon so lets not go there, but "more customized" git services that would offer this as a feature (denial of push request with custom error message) might be a decent Plan C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [pre-commit or pre-push hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). There is no pre-add hook, afaik. With these hooks, you can run any scripts you like, e.g. check file size. Pre-add hooks don't make much sense anyways, since git add only adds to index and only prepares for a commit.